# Why seed value not working fine?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012, and I have a primary key column of type `bigint`.

Sometimes on new insertions it takes a huge jump of 1000 or 10000 for new primary key.

For example:

```
ID
--
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10001
10002
```

Why does this happen? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the behaviour of SQL Server 2012.

To fix this issue, you need to make sure, you add a NO CACHE option in sequence creation / properties like this.

```
 create sequence Sequence1
    as int
    start with 1
    increment by 1
    no cache
go
create table Table1
    (
    id int primary key,
    col1 varchar(50)
    )
go
create trigger Trigger1
    on Table1
    instead of insert
as
insert  Table1
        (ID, col1)
select  next value for Sequence1
,       col1
from    inserted
go
insert Table1 (col1) values ('row1');
insert Table1 (col1) values ('row2');
insert Table1 (col1) values ('row3');

select  * 
from    Table1
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks, It really helped,

_Setting the cache argument to NO CACHE writes the current sequence value to the system tables every time that a sequence is used. This might slow performance by increasing disk access, but reduces the chance of unintended gaps. Gaps can still occur if numbers are requested using the NEXT VALUE FOR or sp_sequence_get_range functions, but then the numbers are either not used or are used in uncommitted transactions._ [more details](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)